# In Delphi, how to detect reliably if a printer is able to print Postscript?

Tags: delphi, printing, postscript

After an extensive searching here and googling around I haven't been able to find a proper response yet (then sorry if this is a duplicated). I'll give some background although I can't disclose much:

I have been working in a software that must print stuff but without allowing the user to preview it or retrieve the contents before it goes to the printer (copyright reasons). I have chosen Postscript because then I could generate the contents for the printer easier, however I need to prevent the content to go to the printer if it's not able to understand Postscript.

I have made a few tests in such printers and if it's not able to understand Postscript it outputs the whole code instead the actual content. It could allow an user with some knowledge to grab that code and generate the page out of my application.

I have found a few codes out there claiming to detect if the printer *supports* Postscript but in my tests it detected printers that are able to understand it as *non-Postscript* printer, then I didn't feel it was reliable way.

Before all, I need to tell that using print spooler is out of plans as the idea is to prevent the users to retrieve the content.

Here is one of the codes I tried that wasn't so reliable:

```
function PrinterSupportsPostscript(dc: hdc): Boolean;
var
TestInt, Err: integer;
a: array[0..255] of char;
s: string;
begin
  Result := false;
  TestInt := GETTECHNOLOGY;

{$IFDEF WIN32}
  if ExtEscape(Dc,QUERYESCSUPPORT,sizeof(TestInt),@TestInt,0,Nil) > 0 then
  begin
    Err := ExtEscape(Dc,GETTECHNOLOGY,0,nil,256,@a);
{$ELSE}
  if Escape(Dc,QUERYESCSUPPORT,sizeof(TestInt),@TestInt,Nil) > 0 then
  begin
    Err := Escape(Dc,GetTechnology,0,nil,@a);
{$ENDIF}
    if Err > 0 then
    begin
      s := UpperCase(StrPas(a));
      if Pos('POSTSCRIPT', s) > 0 then
      result := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Any reliable way to detect that?

Comment: I see this question was marked as duplicated however that question doesn't answer my question, although related. I have tried what was suggested there and it didn't work then I wonder if there is a _more reliable_ way to do that. Thanks for checking though.

Comment: A question is a duplicate if the question is the same

Comment: Well ok. I was seeking for a different answer than what was provided in that question. And since I still cannot post comments to that question I asked my own question. Question may look the same, but I seek a different answer :S I believe I was clear stating that a method didn't work in my case and was the method suggested in that answer. If I wasn't so clear then I apologize and I'll try to formulate a better question next time.